# Doit-on écrire les expressions latines en italique ?

Tags: orthographe, latin, formatage

Lorsqu'on écrit un texte en français et qu'on utilise des expressions latines comme : *a priori*, *a posteriori* etc., doit-on les écrire en italique ?

Quel est le formatage le plus correct pour écrire une expression latine en français ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lorsqu'on écrit un texte en français et qu'on utilise des expressions latines, **on ne les écrit pas en italique *si l'expression est suffisamment entrée dans le vocabulaire ou l'usage courant.***  Autrement, on écrit les expressions étrangères en italique (y compris des expressions latines qui ne sont pas entrées dans le vocabulaire ou dans l'usage courant).

*A priori* et *a posteriori* sont toutes deux d'usage courant.

Quelques remarques sur l'usage des expressions latines.

- D'après la page [Expression latine](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_latine) sur Wikipedia  :

  > Lorsque l'expression est suffisamment entrée dans le vocabulaire courant, il est d'usage de ne plus l'écrire en italique (ce qui est en principe le cas pour les expressions étrangères). Certaines sont à tel point lexicalisées qu'elles peuvent, toujours par dérivation impropre, devenir des noms (« un a priori ») ou prendre des accents. Il existe d'ailleurs des discussions concernant la possibilité d'écrire « un **à** priori » (le latin ne connaît pas les accents, proprement français...)
- Et [une discussion](http://www.langue-fr.net/spip.php?article128) au sujet des expressions latines, liée à ce qui précède.

Comment: Cela signifie que l'on ne doit jamais écrire _a priori_ en italique (puisque l'expression est entrée dans le langage courant) ?

Comment: @Zistoloen Correcte, d'après l'article.

Comment: Donc si j'ai bien compris, pas le droit d'italiciser *ex abrupto* des locutions a priori banales.

Answer (score 0):

Ce n'est pas si clair... Selon le site de l'Office québécois de la langue française (très bien conçu), *ex abrupto* fait partie des « locutions latines courantes. » Cela ne signifie pas pour autant que cette locution doit s'écrire en romain :

> Il est à noter que les locutions et expressions étrangères s'écrivent généralement en italique, du moins en typographie soignée. Toutefois, celles qui sont entrées depuis longtemps dans le vocabulaire français ou qui sont francisées s’écrivent en romain; c’est le cas de plusieurs locutions latines, notamment des expressions courantes comme vice-versa, grosso modo, alter ego ou encore de l’abréviation etc., qui ne sont pratiquement plus perçues comme des mots étrangers. L’usage hésite donc parfois entre l’italique et le romain.